SwiftUI - Always centered text in HStack
I am trying to create a custom navigation bar for my app which has a leading button and a title. The title needs to always be centered, and can be multiline. The easiest way of doing this is with a ZStack, but in this case the text goes over the leading button, which is not OK.
Is there some way of achieving this without getting myself dirty with GeometryReaders and frames? Thanks in advance.
Here is an example code. First ZStack is what I am trying to avoid. Second ZStack is what I am trying to achieve, but without using the .frame modifier.
struct TextView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {           
            
            ZStack(alignment: .center) {
                HStack {
                    Rectangle().fill(.red).frame(width: 20, height: 30)
                    Spacer()
                }
                Text("Text always centered and not over rectangle")
            }
            
            ZStack(alignment: .center) {
                HStack {
                    Rectangle().fill(.red).frame(width: 20, height: 30)
                    Spacer()
                }
                Text("Text always centered and not over rectangle").frame(maxWidth: 320)
            }
        }
        .border(Color.black, width: 2)
        .padding()
        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
    }
}



Could you not just add 20 px of leading padding to the entire VStack?
.padding(.leading, 20) instead of .padding()

Try adding .padding(.horizontal, 20) to the text view. This keeps it away from the red zone, but because it is balanced on both sides, it stays centered.
Text("The text to be centered without touching the red zone")
    .padding(.horizontal, 20) //  HERE



Since you plan on having a button, I started by adding one  with a function that it calls.  I give three examples to show the difference between three, two and one lines.
The formatting of the clear space around the button and the text can be problematic if not applied in a way that makes it difficult for design changing quickly.
None of these uses the .frame modifier.  You could pursue GeometryReader, it is not difficult to grasp and use on layouts.

Here is how to reproduce:

import SwiftUI

struct TextView: View {
    
    private func someButtonAction() {
        // do something userful
        print("Button tapped")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack(alignment: .top) {
                Button(action: {someButtonAction()},
                       label: {Text("Button")})
                Text("Text")
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                
            }.border(Color.red)
            
            HStack {
                Button(action: {someButtonAction()},
                       label: {Text("Button2")})
                
                Text("Text always centered  ")
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                
            }.border(Color.red)
            
            HStack {
                Button(action: {someButtonAction()},
                       label: {Text("Button3")})
                Text("Text always centered and not over rectangle even with multiple lines over two lines")
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            }.border(Color.red)
        }
        Spacer()
    }
}


#Preview {
    TextView()
}


If I understood you correctly, using HStack looking like this should do the trick:
------------------------------
-- BUTTON1 - TEXT - BUTTON2 -- 
------------------------------

If BUTTON2 will be an exact copy of BUTTON1, but with opacity set to 0 (and disabled or with no action), the text stays in the center of the screen and the button is on its left side.
You can put any other View on the right, as long as its width equals the width of the BUTTON1.

Example
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var buttonWidth: CGFloat = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                createButton(action: {
                    // Your action
                })
                
                Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras convallis, sem at varius consectetur, sapien massa congue neque, vitae lacinia ex erat at nisl.")
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                
                createButton(opacity: 0)
                
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
    
    func createButton(opacity: Double = 1,
                      action: (@MainActor () -> Void)? = nil) -> some View {
        Button(action: {
            action?()
        }) { Text("B") }
        .padding()
        .background(Color.red)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .opacity(opacity)
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

Result:

